# How do I execute Visual Studio .cs files in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, visual-studio-2022, transformation

Firstly, I apologise if this is a badly worded question, but I can't think of any other way to explain it.

I have a program that (should) manually add and transform shapes to a Unity environment. The actual "construction" code I have is below in `Bus.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bus
{
    private MyVector _Position { get; set; }
    private MyVector _Rotation { get; set; }
    private MyVector _Scale { get; set; }

    public Bus(MyVector pPosition, MyVector pRotation, MyVector pScale)
    {
        _Position = pPosition;
        _Rotation = pRotation;
        _Scale = pScale;

        InitialiseBus();
    }

    public void InitialiseBus()
    {
        MyMatrix parentScale = MyMatrix.CreateScale(_Scale);
        MyMatrix parentRotationX = MyMatrix.CreateRotationX(_Rotation.X);
        MyMatrix parentRotationY = MyMatrix.CreateRotationY(_Rotation.Y);
        MyMatrix parentRotationZ = MyMatrix.CreateRotationZ(_Rotation.Z);
        MyMatrix parentPosition = MyMatrix.CreateTranslation(_Position);
        MyMatrix parentTransform = parentPosition.Multiply(parentRotationX.Multiply(parentRotationY.Multiply(parentRotationZ.Multiply(parentScale))));

        CreateBus(parentTransform);
    }

    public void CreateBus(MyMatrix pParentTransform)
    {
        CreateBody(pParentTransform);
        CreateWheels(pParentTransform);
    }

    private void CreateBody(MyMatrix pParentTransform)
    {
        GameObject body = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        body.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;

        MyMatrix bodyScale = MyMatrix.CreateScale(new MyVector(4f, 1.5f, 1.5f));

        MyMatrix bodyTransform = pParentTransform.Multiply(bodyScale);
        bodyTransform.SetTransform(body);
    }

    private void CreateWheels(MyMatrix pParentTransform)
    {
        GameObject frontleftwheel = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cylinder);
        GameObject frontrightwheel = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cylinder);
        GameObject backleftwheel = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cylinder);
        GameObject backrightwheel = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cylinder);

        frontleftwheel.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;
        frontrightwheel.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;
        backleftwheel.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;
        backrightwheel.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black;

        MyMatrix wheelScale = MyMatrix.CreateScale(new MyVector(0.8f, 0.2f, 0.8f));

        MyMatrix wheelRotation = MyMatrix.CreateRotationX((float)Math.PI / 2);

        MyMatrix frontleftwheelTranslation = MyMatrix.CreateTranslation(new MyVector(-1.5f, -0.9f, -0.8f));
        MyMatrix frontrightwheelTranslation = MyMatrix.CreateTranslation(new MyVector(-1.5f, -0.9f, 0.8f));
        MyMatrix backleftwheelTranslation = MyMatrix.CreateTranslation(new MyVector(1.5f, -0.9f, -0.8f));
        MyMatrix backrightwheelTranslation = MyMatrix.CreateTranslation(new MyVector(1.5f, -0.9f, 0.8f));

        MyMatrix wheelRotationScale = wheelRotation.Multiply(wheelScale);

        MyMatrix frontleftwheelMatrix = frontleftwheelTranslation.Multiply(wheelRotationScale);
        MyMatrix frontrightwheelMatrix = frontrightwheelTranslation.Multiply(wheelRotationScale);
        MyMatrix backleftwheelMatrix = backleftwheelTranslation.Multiply(wheelRotationScale);
        MyMatrix backrightwheelMatrix = backrightwheelTranslation.Multiply(wheelRotationScale);

        MyMatrix frontleftwheelTransform = pParentTransform.Multiply(frontleftwheelMatrix);
        MyMatrix frontrightwheelTransform = pParentTransform.Multiply(frontrightwheelMatrix);
        MyMatrix backleftwheelTransform = pParentTransform.Multiply(backleftwheelMatrix);
        MyMatrix backrightwheelTransform = pParentTransform.Multiply(backrightwheelMatrix);

        frontleftwheelTransform.SetTransform(frontleftwheel);
        frontrightwheelTransform.SetTransform(frontrightwheel);
        backleftwheelTransform.SetTransform(backleftwheel);
        backrightwheelTransform.SetTransform(backrightwheel);

    }
}
```

Then to call the "construction", I have `CreateEnvironment.cs`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CreateEnvironment : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Bus bus = new Bus(new MyVector(0, 0, 0), new MyVector(0, 0, 0), new MyVector(1, 1, 1));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

For some clarification, all of the Vector, Matrix and Transform methods **work perfectly.**

I have tried running `CreateEnvironment.cs` from Visual Studio using "start without debugging" as I usually do with VS but to no avail. I have also tried pressing "Play" on Unity however this also does not generate the shapes into the environment.

Any advice about the problem or wording for future questions would be appreciated.

Comment: find a unity tutorial or this is going to be the most painful thing you do - but you need to put CreateEnvironment  on a gameobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, and of course, welcome to Unity. Let's clarify a few things. What is Unity, first of all. Obviously, it is a game engine. But this is only the "process flow" part. What is the "technical flow" part? Unity is similar to, in part (but not "really"), a framework. Meaning, what you do in .NET will not work in Unity and vice-versa. Yes, there are tons of workarounds and hacks, but that is not how Unity or .NET are supposed to work. They have as much in common as nuclear physics has to quantum physics. Sure, some concepts match, but they either work together or they create a "bang". Literally. Same for Unity.

Moving on, because it is a game engine, environments usually mean the platforms. Well, yes. In most game engines, but not in Unity. In Unity envs are usually runtime (meaning - when you play), editor (during development) and a sort of a hybrid for tests (usually from the editor) when you either test the code as a pass-through or you can simulate devices (i.e. simulating an iOS device on a Windows device, such as your desktop).

Next, what does Unity allow you to do? Well, just about anything, when we're talking about runtimes. That means that most times you won't do any runtime creation, such as your shape creation. Still, you're approaching this from a C# class constructor so, at most, it's done once. But let's just say that you should approach this with care. What I mean is, in Unity you'll usually **not** be encouraged to use C# class paradigms or patterns except **if needed** (yes, that means whatever you want it to mean as it's left to common sense and a proper project design).

The pattern you'll mostly meet in Unity (in tuts or that you should use - as well as the core of how Unity is built) is the ECS (entity component system) pattern. The closest you'll get to a C# pattern (but not really) is when you're using runtime created SOs (Scriptable Objects), but most of the time, they'll be *passive* assets created at build time, and used in runtime by being dynamically loaded when used (meaning when they're in scope and needed) by the engine.

To rewind all info: in general, you have 4 "categories" (? for lack of a better word) of object types:

- Components (in your case, MonoBehaviours - if you want a discussion on the difference between "simple" comps and MBs, feel free to comment and we can go deeper) - they are mostly instances of classes created at runtime based on the ECS usage (with optional usage of dynamically added or removed comps) but **MUST** be attached to GameObjects in order to work (at dev time in the Editor or at runtime, dynamically from code)
- SOs (Scriptable Objects) - mostly assets that "exist" in the project, but not "visibly" on the heap or stack (although they are loaded by the engine) and "initialized" when they get into scope (again, we can discuss this deeper). They are similar to MBs and at the same time, they are completely different. (yes, it's like how you define love-hate relationships where you can't describe how to relate to a person, that's how *similar* SOs are to MBs)
  -> to complicate things further, the native representation of MBs and SOs is using the same native class internally, even if you have a different hierarchy in C# and different code patterns or events for both
- GOs (game objects) - which is whatever means making your game alive (from weapons to player avatars or menus or whatever else)
- some internals that are loaded via comps (audio components, video components, render components, physics components - basically representation of the engine inside a C# "scripting" runtime)

Now, to your problem. To actually "use" or "run" or "load" a MB, you need to attach it to a GO that exists inside your Scene. (if you wish to discuss Scenes... well, you know the drill). So just add a new `GameObject`, add the `CreateEnvironment` component to it, press **Play** and there you go.

Please note: apart from **VERY FEW** unity classes (such as `GameObject`), do not ever, Ever, Ever, *EVER*, **EVER** instantiate MBs or SOs using `new()`. Yes, it might work, but the app will default to what is know in C and C++ as "undefined behavior". The reason I bring up C and C++ is because Unity is a C++ engine, not a C# engine :)

Also, read the unity manual and API documentation and if you have further questions, let us know!

Good luck!

P.S. there is no `Main()` in Unity. if you want to discuss this, let me know :)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain everything - it works just as you said. Interesting to know .NET and Unity are completely separate things. Seems like I need to visit the Unity manual :)

Comment: Your confusion comes from this: .NET Standard, .NET Framework, .NET Runtime, Unity and... C#. They are not synonyms. C# is the language (which works seamlessly across all three), .NET standard (which is what the .NET frameworks should follow - also not there is a C# Core framework for web apps), the .NET FW is what the MS FW uses and .NET Runtime is most of the libraries (think of the C or C++ "default" headers and libs). The only thing from Microsoft that you use in Unity is C# and *maybe* part of .NET Runtime (maybe !!). I forgot to mention Mono :)

Comment: Also note, when you code a Unity app (not game, as they can be apps meaning XR, VR, AR, mobile apps, TV apps etc.) for Windows you don't use anything Microsoft specific. Not even Windows specific. Unity for Windows means you use the Unity libs on a Windows device. That's it. There is no "Microsoft" or *actual* "Windows" in the equation. So don't confuse .NET "x" concepts with Unity. You have the same code with the same libs for Linux, Android, Windows etc. What changes is the OS. That is assuming you don't use external libs, of course. (because they may have OS specific dependencies or limits)

Comment: One more advice which I did not mention: lookup and get **REALLY** friendly with Prefabs and the `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate()` function. Also when comparing GO tags **do not** use `==`. Use `UnityEngine.GameObject.CompareTag()` instead. It's a few opcodes less and more efficient. It's irrelevant for tests or small games, but used in complex algorithms that run frequently and on mobile devices, trust me, it adds up. Be wary of using `UnityEngine.GameObject.Find*()` funcs. Usually just assign values to variables from the Inspector to existing instances.

Comment: @53R3N1TY Last, but not least, if you want good Unity tuts, check out Brackey's on YouTube. be careful with tuts using workarounds, hacks, abusing `Update()`, using CoRoutines for just about everything, and of course, old Unity versions. The minimum LTS (long term support) version as of now is 2021 for lower versions and 2022 for higher versions. Avoid alphas and betas if you want to make games. Unity 2023 is "sort of" working, but not 100% stable (meaning it still have some bugs or features that might "work" today and behave differently next patch). Good luck! :)